Polars - with_columns on columns that end in a "D" and are of type datetime
I can do the first part with
df.with_columns(pl.col("^.+D$"))

and the second part with
df.with_columns(pl.col(pl.datatypes.Datetime))

How do I join the two conditions with an "and"?

You could use selectors:
import polars.selectors as cs

df.with_columns(cs.datetime() & cs.ends_with('D'))

# or
df.with_columns(cs.datetime() & cs.matches('^.+D$'))


Selectors support set operations such as:
UNION: A | B
INTERSECTION: A & B
DIFFERENCE: A - B
COMPLEMENT: ~A

